# Find the normal plane and osculating plane

Tags: calculus

Find the equations of the normal plane and osculating plane of the helix
$r(t) = cost\mathbf{i} + sint\mathbf{i} + t\boldsymbol{k}$
 at the point $P(0,1,2)$

Comment: The point P =(0,1,2) is not on the helix. Choose another point Q that is on the helix then we can find the equation of the osculating plane and the normal plane.

Answer (score 3):

You know that for describing a plane we need a point and a normal vector. This normal vector is perpendicular to the plane. Here, the normal desired vector is really the tangent vector $T$ (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas)). But what is the point? The point you indicated is not on the curve, so I assumed another point like $A:r(\pi/2)=(0,1,\pi/2)$. We have $$\vec{T}(t)=r'(t)=(-\sin t, \cos t,1)\to \vec{T}(\pi/2)=(-1,0,1)=\vec{n}$$ and this $\vec{n}$ is normal vector. Therefore, we have the equation of normal plane at $A$ is:  $$P: -1(x-0)+0(y-1)+1(z-\pi/2)=0$$. I made a nice plot for this curve and this resulted plane $P$:

[image]

For another part you need to follow the above link and try to find the vector $\vec{B}$. :-)